How to run rocket code from another file?
I can't launch my rocket code from my main file main.rs. I want my main code to run in parallel with the rocket code and remain in the background until I close the process in the terminal.
src\bin\web_page.rs
extern crate rocket;
use rocket::*;

#[get("/<identifier>")]
fn test(identifier: &str) -> String {
    format!("Your identifier is {}", identifier)
}

#[launch]
pub fn rocket() -> _ {
    println!("Rocket started");
    rocket::build().mount("/", routes![test])
}

src\bin\main.rs
mod web_page;

fn main() {

    thread::spawn(|| {
         web_page::rocket().launch()
    });

//other code

}

It only write Rocket start. But server does not work in the background. I tried to check by going to 127.0.0.1:8000/test, but nothing happened. But when I launch with cargo run --bin web_page, everything works. I want the code to work in parallel and independently of everything else, but at the same time not stop my main one.

.launch() returns a Future, which does nothing unless you .await it.  The #[launch] attribute macro generates a main function that sets up the async runtime and then does exactly that, but you're not using it (so it's superfluous).  You either need to use the main function that it generates or else set up the async runtime yourself, eg with Rocket's #[main] attribute macro, and then .await the future.

@eggyal Can you write example?

What does your "main code" that you want "to run in parallel with the rocket code" do?  Perhaps you should attach it as an on_ignite Fairing?

main code creates new tables and works with creating new QR. Raketa processes all requests that come to the IP and depending on the identifier does its actions. Thanks for your tip above, it helped to run the code, but it first starts the server, and until I close it, I can not work with the main code.

Try running rocket::tokio::spawn(web_page::rocket().launch()) instead of web_page::rocket().launch().await. This will spawn the future in the background. Keep in mind that when your main function exits, the server will stop working.

To achieve your goal of running the Rocket server in a background thread while allowing your main code to continue executing, you'll need to start the Rocket server in a non-blocking way.

I was able to solve this problem using asynchrony and a new thread. Now, I have a new thread created, after which my main code runs in parallel
web_pages.rs
#[get("/<identifier>")]
fn test(identifier: &str) -> String {
    format!("Your identifier is {}", identifier)
}


#[launch]
pub fn rocket() -> _ {

    println!("Rocket started");
    rocket::build().mount("/", routes![test])

main.rs
use std::thread;
use tokio::runtime::Runtime;
use web_page::rocket;


#[rocket::main]
async fn main() {

// Create new thread
thread::spawn(|| {
    // Create new Tokio runtime
    let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();

    // Create async function
    rt.block_on(async {
        
        let _start = rocket().launch().await;
    });
});

// Another code
}

